# Use of `anti_join` function in tidyverse

Tags: r, foreign-keys, tidyverse, primary-key

The book R for data science written by Hadley says that

> Check that your foreign keys match primary keys in another table. The best way to do this is with an `anti_join()`

`anti_join(x, y, by = "ID")` gives rows in `x` that was not found in `y` using the `ID`. But I am not sure how it is going to be useful for checking whether the foreign key of one table matches the primary key of another.

Can someone provide an example?

Comment: There are examples in `?anti_join` help page

Comment: @akrun Thanks. I went through the examples given in the book and help page. But was not able to understand what the above statement is trying to make. The below example is much clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the scenario the book tried to describe is the followings:

You have 2 data sets:

```
# data set A
# primary key is ID, foreign key is zip code

A tibble: 10 x 3
      ID zip_code   age
   <int> <chr>    <int>
 1     1 10000       43
 2     2 10001       41
 3     3 10002       46
 4     4 10003       45
 5     5 10004       50
 6     6 10005       48
 7     7 10006       40
 8     8 10007       49
 9     9 10008       44
10    10 AAAAA       42

# data set B
# primary key is zip code

 A tibble: 10 x 2
   zip_code address
   <chr>    <chr>  
 1 10000    B      
 2 10001    H      
 3 10002    U      
 4 10003    M      
 5 10004    T      
 6 10005    O      
 7 10006    P      
 8 10007    R      
 9 10008    L      
10 10009    V
```

You join A and B with `zip_code`. In a real-world situation, there could be no matches in some rows. In this example, it is row 10 for `ID  = 10`.

```
A %>% left_join(B, by = "zip_code")

# A tibble: 10 x 4
      ID zip_code   age address
   <int> <chr>    <int> <chr>  
 1     1 10000       43 B      
 2     2 10001       41 H      
 3     3 10002       46 U      
 4     4 10003       45 M      
 5     5 10004       50 T      
 6     6 10005       48 O      
 7     7 10006       40 P      
 8     8 10007       49 R      
 9     9 10008       44 L      
10    10 AAAAA       42 NA
```

What the book suggested is to use `anti_join` to fish out the no-matches (which could be hard to see if you have thousands of rows) and inspect the foreign key. In this example, `ID = 10` has a totally different kind of foreign key which contributes to no match.

```
A %>% anti_join(B, by = "zip_code")

# A tibble: 1 x 3
     ID zip_code   age
  <int> <chr>    <int>
1    10 AAAAA       42
```

**Data**

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

A <- tibble(ID = 1:10, zip_code = c(seq(10000, 10008, 1), "AAAAA"), age = sample(40:50, 10))

B <- tibble(zip_code =  as.character(seq(10000, 10009, 1)), address = sample(LETTERS, 10))
```